# How to test an internal function

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

I'm trying to create a unit test to cover an internal function

fileA.js

```
module.exports.functionA = () {
  
  const functionB = () {
    // do something
  }

  functionB()
}
```

test.js

```
const { functionA } = require('fileA')

...

it('runs functionB', () => {
  functionA()
  expect(...).toHaveBeenCalled()
}
```

How do I access it?

Comment: You can't unless you expose it somehow. Like `this.functionB = functionB` for instance, which should allow you to run `functionA.functionB()` (note that the fact you're doing this in a test is not really relevant here, you're simply training to access an inner function in general, which isn't possible unless you provide access to it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possibilities here (your situation looks like the first one, but is also clearly simplified for the purposes of the question).

Either:

- `functionB` is entirely private to `functionA`, part of its implementation, which means you can't access it to test it (directly). Instead, test `functionA`, which presumably uses `functionB` as part of the work it does (otherwise, there's no point in an entirely private function in `functionA`).

  or
- `functionA` exposes `functionB` in some way (for instance, as a return value, or as a method on a returned object, or by setting it on an object that's passed in, etc.), in which case you can get it in whatever way `functionA` provides and then test it.

(Again, I think yours is the first case.)